# Dynamic values in static web app configuration file

Tags: azure-static-web-app

I am trying to set dynamic values in azure static web app config files but it doesnt work. Following is the config file. I am trying to replace CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and OPENID_CONFIG_URL with configuration values from configuration tab in static web app.

```
{
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
        "identityprovider": {
          "registration": {
            "clientIdSettingName": "CLIENT_ID",
            "clientCredential": {
              "clientSecretSettingName": "CLIENT_SECRET"
            },
            "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
              "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "{OPENID_CONFIG_URL}"
            }
          },
          "login": {
            "nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/uid",
            "scopes": ["openid", "profile"],
            "loginParameterNames": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["/static/media/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp}", "/static/css/*"]
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json"
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
    }
  ],
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "statusCode": 302,
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/test"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what is the correct format to replace variables with values from configuration tab i static web app?

Tried to use following formats but nothing seems to work.

`${"CLIENT_ID"}`

`$("CLIENT_ID"}`

`$(CLIENT_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a timely response, but I just came across this today.

These are good:

```
  "clientIdSettingName": "CLIENT_ID",  
    "clientCredential": {  
      "clientSecretSettingName": "CLIENT_SECRET"
```

Values come from configuration in Azure or `local.settings.json`

[Azure SWA Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fffx.png)

`local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "CLIENT_ID": "***",
    "CLIENT_SECRET": "***",
    ...
  }
}
```

As for

```
"wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "OPENID_CONFIG_URL"
```

I do not think getting the value from configuration settings is supported yet so you will need to supply a full URL here.

There are several open issues in GH (e.g. [#706](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/706) [#589](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/589)) but they have been there at least a year so...

[This GH issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/519) give some options, including customizing your GitHub workflow to select a specific staticwebapp.config.json file with a static OID config url, which is what I did. Not a great solution, but it works.